# What is this mode and how can I quit it?

Tags: spacemacs

Through some key combinations somehow I am trapped in this mode:

[image]

Orange highlight appears on the left hand side and a orange cursor is activated. It does not look like it is selecting anything.

I tried `CTRL-g` but I cannot get out of this mode.

My questions:

1) What is this mode? It is not obvious in the status bar

[image]

2) How can I get out of this?

Comment: `C-h m` will tell you all of the enabled minor modes.

Comment: `q` normally gets you out of dired-mode. What does that do for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't use spacemacs, but it looks like may be `diff-hl`. See [spacemacs version control](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/tree/master/layers/%2Bsource-control/version-control) and [diff-hl](https://github.com/dgutov/diff-hl).

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Your status bar screenshot says „Dired by name” in the major mode description field, which is the mode you're in (activated by `C-x d`).  It is Emacs' equivalent to your usual GUI file manager.  To leave it, just press `q` (or `C-k` if spacemacs is in evil mode and does not recognize q), to learn what you can do here, press `C-h m` to get a description of the mode and the key bindings.  If you're interested in going deeper, I'd recommend `C-h i m emacs` (the manual of Emacs in the Info reader) and reading the `dired` documentation.</strike>

Sorry, I mistook the question for an Emacs-newcomer one.  The orange hints in the gutter area seem to be version control notifications (see the comments below).

Comment: My question is about what mode causes the orange highlight. It is not about the dired mode.

Comment: oh, sorry, I mistook your question for a newbie one then.  Since the orange is in the gutter area –– do you use a version control system on that directory?  It resembles a VCS notification of changes.

Comment: Or, asked the other way around, can you approximately recall those „some key combinations”?

Comment: Answer to your earlier comment: I am using git in that directory; Sorry I cannot remember the key sequence. That's why I posted this question about how to find it out. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome.  Does that mean we have found the solution?  In that case, I'd just update the crossed-out answer ;-)